# Add new row of values to Pandas DataFrame in specific row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add after the Gross profit line in an income statement new line with some values from array.
I tried just to append it in the location but nothing changed.

```
income_statement.loc[["Gross Profit"]].append(gross)
```

The only way i succeed doing something similar is by making it another dataframe and concat it to end of the income_statement.

I'm trying to make it look like that:(The 'gross' line in yellow)
[image]
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample `df` that tried to look similar to yours (see below).

```
df

      Unnamed: 0  2010  2011  2012  2013  ...  2016  2017  2018  2019  TTM
0   gross profit    10    11    12    13  ...    16    17    18    19  300
1  total revenue     1     2     3     4  ...     7     8     9    10  400
```

The aim now would be to add a row between them ('gross'), with the values you have listed in the picture.

One way to add  the row could be with `numpy.insert`, which returns an `array` back so you have to convert back to a `pd.DataFrame`:

```
# Store the columns of your df
cols = df.columns

# Add the row (the number indicates the index position for the row to be added,1 is the 2nd row as Python indexes start from 0)
new = pd.DataFrame(np.insert
                   (df.values, 1, values = ['gross',22, 45, 65,87,108,130,151,152,156,135,133], axis=0),
                   columns=cols)
```

Which gets back:

```
new

      Unnamed: 0 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019  TTM
0   gross profit   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19  300
1          gross   22   45   65   87  108  130  151  152  156  135  133
2  total revenue    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10  400
```

Hopefully this will work for you. Let me know for issues.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote it like that : income_statement=pd.DataFrame(np.insert(income_statement.values,1,values= gross,axis=0),columns=cols)  in values i only put the array. and it removed the index column so instead of "Gross Profile", "Total Revenue" etc i got only the numbers. any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: It is because ```insert``` returns an ```array``` and you have to convert back to a dataframe. That is why I wrap the command with ```pd.DataFrame...```. Did you also run the ```cols = df.columns```? And is your dataframe also called ```df```?

Comment: yes and my dataframe called income_statement. income_statement=pd.read_csv('company.csv',index_col=0,skipinitialspace=True)
cols=income_statement.columns

Comment: Try changing ```cols=df.columns``` to ```cols=income_statement.columns``` and try it again?

Comment: wrote it like this: income_statement=pd.read_csv('company.csv',index_col=0,skipinitialspace=True) cols=income_statement.columns

Comment: I don't mean in your ```pd.read_csv``` command. Just read in the file as you did. And when you do that, create a variable called ```cols``` that consists of your dataframe columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229510/discussion-between-sophocles-and-adirb).